# Blender Timeline jump Frames

Tags: animation, timeline, dopesheet

im learning animations and im working on duplicate the model and the animations of this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=odwQbnA4ErM

But im struggling at 2:43. It seems like not every Frame is played to get that specific light.Someone maybe knows how to do that?Here is what my Dope Sheet looks like:
[image]

Comment: hello, maybe share your file (only the useful objects)? upload and copy paste the URL: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: hi moonboots, thanks for the quick respond. Here is the url https://pasteall.org/blend/70abf75e340547fb900ef83be45e20ac

Comment: what do you mean by "not every Frame is played to get that specific light", your animation seems to work fine

Comment: Yes my animation works but it looks different from the video. If i play my animation each line of light goes on and off at a time. But in the video at 2:44 and at 0.25 speed there are always 2 line of lights next to ech other at the same time which gives a different effect when played.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I don't think that they are on at the same time, it's just that while one tends to fade in, the previous tends to fade out and so on, so between the keyframes you'll always have 2 lights on (only one can be 100% on though), I guess it's that, no?

Comment: Also maybe switch from bezier interpolation to linear (select all and press T), it gives a different effect

Comment: I looked again and yes you´re right, they are not on at the same time it´s between the keyframes like you said. Is it possible to let the blue line in the timeline jump like from frame 16 directly to 32 when i play the animation? I get nearly the result when i hold left click at the blue line in the timeline, pres ctrl at the same time and move the mouse right or left. Change to linear helped but doesnt give me the desired result.

Comment: No you can't jump from a frame to another, the best way to manage actions is to use the NLA (Nonlinear Animation editor), it allows to easily move and repeat action strips, but I don't think you can manage node actions with the NLA, it's probably why he uses the Dope Sheet for his animation. You could probably use Geometry Nodes but I don't know them enough...